# what is the equivalent to rspec's 'it "should …", focus: true do' in minitest/spec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, minitest

In my tests in projects that use `rspec` I often use a 'focus' while developing to save running all the tests when I want to focus on just one or a few specific test cases.

In Minitest (using the spec syntax extensions in this case) I can't find an equivalent.

#### In `rspec`

```
it "should work properly", focus: true do
  # stuff
end
```

what's the equivalent in Minitest?

Answer (score 6):

Install the [minitest-focus](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest-focus) gem, add `require "minitest/focus"` to your test or helper, and insert `focus` before the test method you want to focus on.

Test-style:

```
focus
def test_work
  assert work.done?
end
```

Spec-style:

```
focus
it "should work properly" do
  work.must_be :done?
end
```

Comment: alas it's not compatible with minutest v5 and going by the issues thread does not seem to work under bundler / rake either.

Comment: Version 1.1.0 added Minitest 5 compatibility.

Comment: Yep - as of last night! Alas it breaks in my app.  Will look into why today.